# Getting access to data in jade template (to make static html)

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, gruntjs

I am trying to pass some data to jade template to generate static content. I do not know much about node.js and express, I don't use them as backend. I use jade as a template engine and to generate static html.

There are lot of request in jade issue list about having [multi line code](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/405), and the owner comments

> I'd like to promote keeping too much js out of the templates, maps etc
>   can be exposed via locals
>
> if there's a lot of logic or objects etc within a template you should
>   be using app.helpers() etc, they can still be view-only helpers but at
>   least it keeps the templates cleaner

I am not quite sure how to do this in a [grunt based](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jade) environment. Basically, if I can get access to javascript variables (which may be a text, js or json file) in my jade template, so I can use the data in my template and generate static html files. What is the best way to do this?

---

### Edit

To clarify further, I may have data like (say in a json file)

```
user1 = {link: '', lbl: 'User', txt: '.... lot 0f text ....'}
user2 = {link: '', lbl: 'User', txt: '.... lot 0f text ....'}
```

in my mixin, somehow I need to access user1, user2 etc in my jade template

```
.content
        +colum(user1 )
        +colum(user2 )

mixin colum(d)
    .span4
        h4
            | #{d.lbl}
        p
            | #{d.txt}
```

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do it with grunt-contrib-jade try the `data` option:

```
jade: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      data: function(dest, src) {
        // Return an object of data to pass to templates
        return require('./userData.json');
      },
    },
    files: {
      "dest.html": ["templates/*.jade"]
    },
  },
}
```

Here are the docs on it: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jade#data

Comment: If the JSON isn't a module, I found that `return grunt.file.readJSON('userData.json');` worked where `require()` would cause an error: "Error: Cannot find module 'userData.json'".

Answer (score 1):

You can render your data in jade with: #{your_variable}

Comment: I added some clarification. Rather than how to use a variable, it is more how to pass the variable in a non express/node context. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps: The jade public API https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme

Update: after play around for awhile, I got this:

```
var jade = require('jade');

// Compile a function
var fn = jade.compile('p= data');
console.log(fn({'data':'test'}));
```

When I ran this code, I got: `<p>test</p>`. So here is how jade can work:

jade.complie(jadeString) is a function to determine what string that jade have to complie - the `jadeString` parameter, you can use `fs` module to load the content of your jade template and place it here. fn(jsonData) is the function that actually complie the jade template to html, jsonData is the data you want to use in the template.

Comment: +1 thanks Rikky.. i re-read the documentation, and stumbled upon `locals`  option. This jade plugin accepts it. https://github.com/phated/grunt-jade . have you used it? thanks again